# Alfresco CMIS 1.0 performance with AtomPUB vs WebServices binding

Tags: performance, alfresco, cmis

which CMIS 1.0 binding is more performant (and best practice) for use with Alfresco 4.2.3?
Is it AtomPUB or WebServices?

Client library we use is DotCMIS 0.6

Thanks and Best regards,
Robert Rosić

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best binding is the AtomPUB due to the lack of processing SOAP messages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I searched for that info everywehere with little luck. Official docs and wikis just give specs how to connect but not what is preffered way.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](https://www.vodori.com/blog/alfresco-performance-with-cmis/):

> After all of our research, we ended up accidentally stumbling across one thing that made the biggest difference. If you’re familiar with the CMIS spec, you may know that it defines two “bindings”, or APIs for communicating between client (Pepper) and server (Alfresco). One of these is the AtomPub binding which defines certain extensions to the Atom standard. The other is the Web Services binding, which follows SOAP, WSDL and Web Services standards. **At first we had only been using the AtomPub binding, but when we started testing out the Web Services binding we noticed that search performance doubled.** It was the same on both 3.3.3 and 3.4.0.